# Android remove setOnGenericMotionListener()

Tags: java, android, view

how to remove setOnGenericMotionListener() ?

```
view.setOnGenericMotionListener(this);
```

Thanks

Comment: Just a guess: `view.setOnGenericMotionListener(null)`?

Comment: I use it, but I don't know if this is a good solution.

Comment: Well, the only other option I can think of is to pass a no-op argument (i.e., an implementation of the interface that does nothing). But based on the name of this method and how it presumably works, passing `null` seems the correct solution. Sorry, I'm only somewhat familiar with the Android API, otherwise I'd be more definitive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work, depending on your use-case.

```
view.setEnabled(false);
```

An alternative could be making the overrides in the OnGenericMotionListener do nothing.

EDIT: As mentioned by @Slaw, `view.setOnGenericMotionListener(null)` also works, and if I had to guess is probably what you want to use.